# How to get the text from mp4 or mp3 file while it is running

Tags: python, speech-recognition, mp3, mp4, speech-to-text

Is there is a way to run the video or audio file with python and write what it say in the same time?

Comment: take a look at gstreamer

Comment: I will see it thanks

Comment: What text? Are you asking about speech recognition?

Comment: Yes but i want it to recognize the speech while the file is running